# How do I make the folderview plasmoid for plasma desktop use nautilus?

Tags: gnome, kubuntu, plasma

I have plasma desktop but I can't seem to find a way to get the plasmoid to point to nautilus. It always asks how to open filetype "file:///". The fact this is a protocol even weirder.

Answer (score 1):

**"I can't seem to find a way to get the plasmoid to point to nautilus."**

How did you ?

With the Kubuntu/KDE the plasma widget folderview (Folder Views) /1/ is using the system's default application. System Settings > Default Applications and System Settings > File Associations.

[image]

1. http://userbase.kde.org/Plasma#Folder_Views